# Optimize JOIN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

This is my MySQL in general:

```
SELECT *
FROM
     Table1
     INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.Table2_id = Table2.id) 
     INNER JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.Table3_id = Table3.id) 
     INNER JOIN Table4 ON (Table1.Table4_id = Table4.id) 
     INNER JOIN Table5 ON (Table1.Table5_id = Table5.id) 
     LEFT JOIN Table6 ON (Table1.Table6_id = Table6.id)  
ORDER BY Table1.barcode DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

I put index on all the ID (By default there is but for being sure I rechecked them) and also for `Table1.barcode`.

It's a very slow query on my database (about 15 secs).

I check it without `order by` and as I excepted that was really fast.

I remove `limit 50` and `order by`, it took the same time (about 15 secs).

I should say that there are for sure lots of data:

```
Table1: 300442 records,
Table2: 77 records,
Table3: 314085 records,
Table4: 28987 records,
Table5: 127805 records,
Table6: 3230 records
```

I want to make it fast.

Maybe I can change the * to the field that I need (So I try to do it).

Is changing the join order would help me?

I can increase the memory of server and also the number of CPU and the speed of CPU, in my query which of them is more effective?

Is there any other recommendation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables? If more than one is not a 1:1 relationship with table1, your query is highly questionable.

Comment: @Uueerdo All are 1:N except Table1 and Table3

Comment: Then your query makes little sense unless you are trying to get every combination of the records of table2, table4, and table5 that are associated with the same record of table1. If there are X, Y, Z records from t4, t5, and t6 (respectively) associated with a record in t1; you will have X*Y*Z records in the result for those records.

Comment: @Uueerdo Actually I retrieve the query of CakePHP to raw query for showing here. There is a search in the web application that is used in all part of project, which is why it's like that. It works good except in on entity that has lots of data

Comment: Lots of queries tend to work fine when there is very little data; a good query should work well (within reason) when there is lots of data. If you actually need such a "sub" cross product, you are often better off doing so client side.

Comment: @Uueerdo This query will be used not a lot but at least once in a day. About the server specification, whats your idea?

Comment: A bad query is exponentially bad, so the best hardware can't always save you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perhaps try to use explain and figure out what is going on:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

> > Is changing the join order would help me?

The join order usually does not matter since most engines would do the order optimization internally. Some also have a way to force join order and check yourself whether for your case you might get better results with a specific order that is different than what the engine generated.

> > I can increase the memory of server and also the number of CPU and the speed of CPU, in my query which of them is more effective?

I would focus on memory (caching, shared_buffer) but before doing any server change you should first investigate the actual issue well and try to tune your existing system. (for ideas see: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization (General Setup and Optimization section)

> > Maybe I can change the * to the field that I need (So I try to do it).

Definitely. Prefer that to * in general.

Comment: It's not all of my answer. Would you mind answer them (e.g server specifications) so I'll mark your answer as the answer of my question.